# Set default File opening programs

Tags: mp3, winamp

Working on Vista & Windows 7, I use Winamp 5.57 for listening to MP3 and VLC player for watching movies.

I made those two as my default players for corresponding media respectively. But when I launch Winamp for playing MP3, some of the video files (like .flv, etc.,) automatically get changed the file opening mode to Winamp player. This happens every time even if I set it back to 'default program'.

How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the settings in the Winamp preferences (I think it might be under Winamp agent, haven't got it installed on any machine I can currently access) for something along the lines of "preserve file associations".